# Executing <Script> elements injected into the DOM

Tags: yui

I've been attempting to add the Google Tag Manager script to a website developed with Squarespace. Unfortunately Google implementation guidelines specify that this script should be inserted immediately after the opening `<body>` tag, something Squarespace doesn't permit.

Consequently, I've been playing around with YUI library to attempt to inject this code to where it is required. And have this:

```
<script>
Y.use('node', function() {
    Y.on('domready', function() {
        obj = Y.Node.create('<!-- Google Tag Manager --><noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KPT4S5" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>'+'<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({\'gtm.start\':new Date().getTime(),event:\'gtm.js\'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],'+'j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=\'+l:\'\';j.async=true;j.src=\'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\'+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);'+'})(window,document,\'script\',\'dataLayer\',\'GTM-KPT4S5\');<\/script><!-- End Google Tag Manager -->');
        Y.one('body').prepend(obj);
    });
});
</script>
```

The code above will inject the Script where required, but it wont execute it. Could someone help identify why and possibly suggest a solution please?

Incidentally, I know I can achieve this with jQuery, but I dont wish to load any additional libraries.

Many thanks.

N.B Apologies, I wasn't clear in my original post. I dont have access to the source code in Squarespace and I need to insert the GTM script directly after the opening `<body>` tag. I can insert scripts into the `<head>` in Squarespace so my attempt was to inject GTM code to the `<body>` from there.

Answer (score 1):

You can use document.write to execute the inline script code that you've inserted as DOM text. So instead of

```
<script>
Y.use('node', function() {
    Y.on('domready', function() {
        obj = Y.Node.create('<!-- Google Tag Manager --><noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KPT4S5" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>'+'<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({\'gtm.start\':new Date().getTime(),event:\'gtm.js\'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],'+'j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=\'+l:\'\';j.async=true;j.src=\'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\'+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);'+'})(window,document,\'script\',\'dataLayer\',\'GTM-KPT4S5\');<\/script><!-- End Google Tag Manager -->');
        Y.one('body').prepend(obj);
    });
});
</script>
```

You can do

```
<script>
document.write('<!-- Google Tag Manager --><noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KPT4S5" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>'+'<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({\'gtm.start\':new Date().getTime(),event:\'gtm.js\'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],'+'j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=\'+l:\'\';j.async=true;j.src=\'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\'+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);'+'})(window,document,\'script\',\'dataLayer\',\'GTM-KPT4S5\');<\/script><!-- End Google Tag Manager -->');
</script>
```

**Edit:** If the JS is from a third party source that you don't have access to, you need to execute the inline JS code yourself through [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp). You can do something similar to this

```
<script>
Y.use('node', function() {
    Y.on('domready', function() {
        obj = Y.Node.create('<!-- Google Tag Manager --><noscript><iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-KPT4S5" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe></noscript>'+'<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({\'gtm.start\':new Date().getTime(),event:\'gtm.js\'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],'+'j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!=\'dataLayer\'?\'&l=\'+l:\'\';j.async=true;j.src=\'//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=\'+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);'+'})(window,document,\'script\',\'dataLayer\',\'GTM-KPT4S5\');<\/script><!-- End Google Tag Manager -->');
        obj.id="googleTag";
        Y.one('body').prepend(obj);
        Y.one('#googleTag').all('script').each(function(s, k) {
            var scriptSrc = s.getHTML();
            eval(scriptSrc);
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Ahh sorry, I wasn't clear. I dont have access to the source code in Squarespace and I need to insert the GTM script directly after the opening <body> tag. I can insert scripts into the <head> in squarespace so I can inject it to the <body> from there.

Answer (score 0):

Though this question is a bit older, it is possible to add Google Tag Manager's code in the Code Injection section of Squarespace in the "footer" area.

With administrator access, choose:

`Settings -> Advanced -> Code Injection`

Place your GTM script in the header and the `<noscript>` stuff in the footer.

I know this doesn't solve the particular point about getting it immediately after the opening `<body>` tag, but I have seen this proposed (and used it myself on a few client sites that were done in Squarespace).